# Dell laptop adapter compatibility

Tags: compatibility

I want to know if Dell adapter PA-4E family with P/N JU012 and REF No:ADP-130DB B, is compatible with my Dell Vostro 1400 laptop, S/N: 2Z5T7G1. The only diff I see is with my old adaptr the i/p current is 1.5A and the new 2.5 A and the old o/p current is 3.34A, new 6.7 A. Picture of both old and new attached.

Comment: The current difference may seem small but it can certainly fry the circuits.

Comment: As long as the voltage is + or - 1 volt and the amps are equal to or greater it will work. I see no attached pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Dell certified refurbisher with extensive experience with these products I can affirm with certainty the PA-4E is fully compatible the Vostro 1400. It is a 130W adapter compared to the original 90W hence the amperage differences. This does not harm the device. It would be a problem in reverse. Using a higher wattage power adapter would never cause a problem. It may even result in faster charge time. Both of the adapters are 19.5V. Unlike voltage, which is a constant, the watts rating of a power supply indicates what it’s capable of, it doesn't have to use all 130W.